# Radius of convergence and analytic

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kz^k$ be a power series with radius of convergence $R<\infty$. I know that $f(z)$ is analytic for $|z|<R$, but is it true that $f(z)$ is not analytic for $|z|>R$?

Intuitively, I think it is true, and I know that $f(z)$ converges absolutely for $|z|<R$ and diverges for $|z|>R$, but how can I use this fact to find some contradiction (if we assume $f(z)$ is analytic for $|z|<R'$, where $R'>R$)?

Comment: Did you try any concrete example at all? Say, the simplest power series with finite radius of convergence, which could be $f(z)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty z^n$...

Answer (score 0):

The series diverges for $|z| > R$.  So if you're defining $f$ as the sum of the power series, that is not defined (and therefore not analytic) for $|z|>R$.

There might be (and often is) another definition of $f$ that makes it analytic on a domain that includes some or all of $|z|>R$.

On the other hand, $f$ can't be made to be analytic for $|z| < R'$ where $R' > R$, because there is a theorem that says if $f$ is analytic on $|z|<R'$, its Maclaurin series has radius of convergence $\ge R'$.

Answer (score 0):

No.

$f(z)=1/(1+z^2)$ has r.o.c.=1 if expanded around $0$, but it is analytic everywhere except $\pm i$.

Actually, what $R$ tells is, when you choose a certain "good"(analytic) point as the centre, the largest possible circle you can draw such that each point within the circle is analytic. But it tells nothing about what happens on or outside the circle.